# Scala compilation time report

Tags: scala, scalac

I've got a project that isn't a crazy number of lines of code, but its compilation time is really long on a clean compile. I have the feeling there are some hotspots, but I don't know how to find them. Is there a way to get a report of how long various compilation phases are taking on different parts of my codebase, so that I try to optimize?

Comment: https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/tag/v2.12.3: "Compiler performance has improved significantly and is now automatically benchmarked after each change." Maybe that will help?

Comment: @anandsun That's great, but it still misses the need for information to tune compilation of a given codebase. Unless they've achieved an order-of-magnitude improvement or something!

Comment: Yeah agreed, sorry I don't know the answer to your initial question, so I just commented instead of answering since this speedup may also be of interest to you.

Comment: Have you checked this? https://github.com/scalacenter/scalac-profiling

Comment: It looks like that was created later in the year from when I asked the question, but yeah, it's probably very much in line with what I was looking for!